# Storing prepared statements as static members

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I have 15 prepared statements that I will be using very frequently throughout my application. A few of them will be called several million times during a single task.

I have decided to use prepared statements since parsing a regular statement a million times does not seem like a good idea.

I am planning to create a utility class that will manage all database-related things and all of the prepared statements. The statements will be stored as static members which I can call by passing in the appropriate arguments.

Are there any issues with storing prepared statements as static members that I should be aware of?

I am using [sqlite-jdbc](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/) if that makes a difference.

EDIT:

This is how I'm planning to manage my prepared statements

```
class DBUtils {

   private static PreparedStatement psInsertPerson;

   public static void createStatements() {
      // assuming a connection has been set up already
      psInsertPerson = conn.prepareStatement( ... );
   }

   public static void insertPerson( ... ) {
      psInsertPerson.set...
      psInsert.addBatch();

      // figure out when to perform batch insertion at some point
   }
}
```

Comment: How will you guarantee that the Connection exists before these are initialised?  Wouldn't it be better to have them as instance variables so you can better control when they are created?

Comment: Can you rewrite your query to select more records at a time to reduce the number of queries? Can you create a stored procedure instead of sending the query across?

Comment: @DavidWallace I can resolve that by establishing the connection before a task begins, or just having a connection around for the life of the application.

Comment: @John Most of these are INSERT or UPDATE queries. I have complete control over the database since I am creating the database on the fly and destroying it after I'm done with it, so if stored procedures are preferable over prepared statements I can re-consider my design.

Comment: @MxyL Can you really resolve make such a guarantee?  I'm not sure how you'd do it, if you're going to have the class loader creating prepared statements.

Comment: @Mxyl OH! I have just the thing for you sir. Introducing BULK INSERT. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: @DavidWallace I am under the impression that if I just do a `getConnection` at the beginning and never close it until I'm done with it, it would be available whenever I need it. So for example, I can have the task establish a connection, prepare the statements, and then go off on its way.

Comment: @John I have not heard of bulk inserts before but it looks like sqlite supports it and would be useful for reducing the number of queries I need to make (there are several places where a single bulk insert can be done instead of a 100k separate inserts)

Comment: @MxyL I think DavidWallace is right. The problem with a static member is that you have poor (no?) control over its creation time. The static members might be initialized before you can create the connection. Better use normal members and make sure you only create one object of that class.

Comment: @SebastianH I might be using the term "static member" carelessly. I've added some code to describe how I'm going to be using it. But yes, now that I think about it, someone might try to do things in way I didn't expect, so if I force users to instantiate an object first, that would guarantee that the connection will be setup during the construction.

Comment: In general, do not try to reinvent the wheel.  Look into using Hibernate or MyBatis (or old iBatis) for your JDBC needs.  I'm sure there are other tools for this that work equally well.  Roll-your-own JDBC solutions are generally terrible.

Comment: @DwB I am not sure how using a sqlite jdbc is considered reinventing the wheel. Wouldn't that be the same idea as using Hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it with statics. Use the Apache DBCP connection pool as your DataSource, and configure it to pool PreparedStatements as well.